# Razor / C# - create incrementing array names in loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, arrays, razor

I am just trying to learn razor syntax for webmatrix and I am struggling with arrays and cant find any guidance, can someone show me where I am going wrong..cheers

```
 @for(var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {   

    int[] new monthArray[i];

  }
```

I need to create 12 arrays named as:

```
monthArray1
monthArray2
monthArray3
.......
monthArray12
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a matrix (e.g., an array of 12 arrays, for a total of 144 elements)?

Comment: thanks for responding...no just 12 arrays

Comment: Right now, what you're doing is re-declaring the same array in each pass through the loop, each time one element longer, then throwing it all away because you're declaring the variable inside the loop.

Comment: thanks..so how do i code this so its not the same array and i am declaring a new one with an incrementing name on each loop

Comment: I think I can better help if I have more context. Why do you need twelve arrays? What are you storing?

Comment: array1 will be January, array2 will be February etc. for each array will be several results of sql queries, the array will allow me total each column...ive done this in php but cant work out the razor syntax for this

Comment: Ahhh... gotcha. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a single two-dimensional array?

```
int[][] monthArrays = new int[12][];
@for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    monthArrays[i] = new int[foo]; // foo is length of each array
}
```

Then, access the right array by month number.
For example, instead of monthArray3, you'd write

```
monthArrays[3] ... // do something with array
```

Comment: Exactly what I was getting to.